# Change the Stripes HTTP Response Code

Tags: java, http, response, stripes

I'm using the Stripes framework to develop a Java app.

I need to return my custom HTTP response codes, I mean, sometimes in an ActionBean I want to return something different to "200 OK" when I create or update some object.

I'm not able to find any documentation about this. Some help??

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

as in

```
getContext().getResponse().setStatus(500);
```